# Remove all album art images in multiple mp3 from multiple directories in single process

Tags: mp3, album-art

How to remove all album art images in multiple mp3 from multiple directories in single process?

Is there any web-utility /software that I can use ?

I don't want to edit single mp3 album art and save it.

Comment: do you wish to remove album art or update them ?

Comment: What system are you asking about here?

Answer (score 11):

Try [eyeD3](http://eyed3.nicfit.net/).

```
eyeD3 --remove-all-images */*.mp3
```

You could specify the directory further if required, this will just remove all artwork embedded in files in the current directory.

Comment: For me I had to use `--remove-images`.

Comment: you can install it with pip : `sudo pip install eyeD3`

Comment: I had to use `eyeD3 --remove-all-images */*.mp3`. This will remove embeded images in every mp3 files in subdirectories of the current directory, but only on the subdirectory level.

Comment: @GuillaumeVincent And to install pip: `sudo apt install python-pip
`.

Comment: this app crashes with the error `eyed3:ERROR: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'file_info'`

Comment: `eyeD3: error: unrecognized arguments: --remove-images`, the argument have been changed to `--remove-all-images`

Comment: @LajosMészáros, indeed, this seems to be the case since [at least v0.7.0](https://github.com/nicfit/eyeD3/blob/v0.7.0/src/eyed3/plugins/classic.py), which is from 2012.

Answer (score 5):

For Windows, there is a program called "[taghycardia](http://taghycardia.info)" that can do batch cover art removal from multiple mp3 files/folders without much hassle. It can also optionally extract the images into respective folders.

Answer (score 3):

I love [MP3Tag](http://mp3tag.de/en/download.html), one of the best utilities for what you're looking for.

http://mp3tag.de/en/download.html

Comment: This is a windows app.

Answer (score 0):

I tried 3 programs on the 3 copies of an mp3 with album art image, all the 3 changed the file so that Totem media player did not display the image after, but:

- eyeD3 : commandline, the filesize remains the same !
- EasyTAG : slow graphical interface, resulting file is larger !!!
- Audio Tag Tool : significantly smaller filesize, responsive graphical interface, however it can only delete the whole tag (i.e. artist, title, album, etc, not just image), called "tagtool" in the ubuntu repo

All 3 have batch mode.